# How to get max CPU percentage from from 5 trials

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am new to Powershell and struggling with syntax.
I want to write a script which gives me max CPU usage by a process out of 5 attempts.

```
$properties=@(
@{Name="Process Name"; Expression = {$_.name}},
@{Name="CPU (%)"; Expression = {$_.PercentProcessorTime}},    
@{Name="Memory (MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.workingSetPrivate / 1mb),2)}}
)
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | Select-Object $properties
```

I have to run the above process 5 times and pick the top process which has max CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you want (remember to also include your definition of `$properties`):

```
1 .. 5 |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process
    } | Where-Object Name -notin '_Total','Idle' |
            Sort-Object -Property 'PercentProcessorTime' -Descending |
                Select-Object -First 1 -Property $properties
```

`1 .. 5` is the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#range-operator-), which generates the set of numbers 1,2,3,4,5.  This is just a quick hack to run `ForEach-Object` 5 times.

`Where-Object Name -notin '_Total','Idle'` excludes some 'processes' that always have high values but are unlikely to be what you're looking for.  Generally it is more efficient to [update the call](https://www.darkoperator.com/blog/2013/3/11/introduction-to-wmi-basics-with-powershell-part-3-wql-and-se.html) to `Get-WmiObject` to exclude these at that stage, but for clarity I went with this technique.

`Sort-Object -Property 'PercentProcessorTime' -Descending` takes all of the readings and sorts them in order from largest CPU value to lowest.

`Select-Object -First 1 -Property $properties` Selects just the first object in the sorted list (i.e. the one with the highest value).  Note that it is better to do this last and not after each call to `Get-WmiObject` as it creates a new custom object for each WMI one returned, almost all of which we discard further along the line - it is more efficient to do this 'duplication' for only the final object we select.